# RUBY Exit minesweeper game loop

Tags: ruby, minesweeper

I can't figure out how to exit the game loop. I'm having a hard tried making a `lose?` function, I tried doing like `lose?(x)` that would return true when `x==1` but that didn't get it to exit the `run` method. Here's my code for the Game class.

```
class Minesweeper

    attr_accessor :board

    def initialize
        @board = Board.new
    end

    def run
        puts "Welcome to minesweeper!"
        x = nil
        play_turn until win? || lose?(x)
    end

    def play_turn
            board.render
            pos, command = get_input
            debugger
            if !explode?(pos, command)
                board.set_input(pos,command)
            else
                puts "You lose!"
                lose?(1)
            end
    end

    def explode?(pos, cmd)
        board.grid[pos[0]][pos[1]].bomb && cmd == "reveal"
    end

    def get_input
        pos = nil
        command = nil
        until pos && check_pos(pos)
            puts "What position?"
            pos = parse_pos(gets.chomp)
        end
        until command && check_command(command)
            puts
            puts "What would you like to do (e.g. reveal, flag... ~ else?)"
            command = gets.chomp
            puts
        end
        [pos, command]
    end

#Some code here (check_pos, etc)



    def lose?(x)
        return true if x == 1
        false
    end

    def win?
        # board.all? {}
    end


end
```

I had `explode?` in the `Board` class before, but for the sake of being able to end the game, moved it here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It never exits because on each loop you check `lose?(x)` and x is always the same - `nil`, - so you get false each time. Your `else` clause inside `play_turn` is meaningless - with the current `until` you need this control flow outside of `play_turn` to work. Technically, you can replace `lose(1)` with `exit` within `play_turn` and your code should work (kind of), but I'd suggest some refactoring instead...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov, what kind of refactoring would you suggest? Maybe no until `win? || lose?`

Answer (score 0):

If we expand your `run` method, a little, it becomes more obvious what the issue is:

```rb
def run
  puts "Welcome to minesweeper!"
  x = nil
  until(win? || lose(x)) do
    play_turn
  end
end
```

In this method, you're creating a new variable `x` which is scoped to this method and has a value of `nil`. This variable is never set in the scope of that method, so is always `nil`, meaning that the check `win? || lose(x)` could also be written `win? || lose(nil)`, and `lose` will never return true.

If you return a value from your `play_turn` method, you can then use that. Note that the result of the last thing executed in the method is what is returned:

```rb
def play_turn
  board.render
  pos, command = get_input
  debugger

  if !explode?(pos, command)
    board.set_input(pos,command)
    true
  else
    puts "You lose!"
    false
  end
end
```

which means your `run` method can then check the result:

```rb
def run
  puts "Welcome to minesweeper!"

  # we now know that play_turn returns true if the turn was not a loser
  # (i.e. it should continue to the next loop) and false if the player
  # lost, so we can use that returned value in our loop.
  while(play_turn) do
    if win?
      puts "looks like you won!"
      # if the player wins, we want to exit the loop as well. This is done
      # using break
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this also means that you don't need a separate `lose` method